# Inject database connection pool

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, macwire

I have started using MacWire for the dependency injection of my Play app, and I am having problems trying to inject the database connection.

Before using DI, my code looked like this:

```
DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
  ...
}
```

This is not working anymore after using DI. I get the following exception: `java.lang.InstantiationException: play.api.db.DBApi`.

My application loader:

```
class Loader extends ApplicationLoader {
  def load(context: Context) = {
    val components = new BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) with Components
    components.application
  }
}
```

The main components of the app:

```
trait Components extends BuiltInComponents with I18nComponents
                 with RepositoryModule {

  lazy val assets: Assets = wire[Assets]
  lazy val router: Router = wire[Routes] withPrefix "/"
}
```

And the repository module:

```
trait RepositoryModule {
  lazy val userRepository = wire[UserRepository]
}
```

How can I get and use a database connection pool and inject it so it can be used within the repository?

Comment: Similar situation with compile time DI and connection pool instantiation -- were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Yes. Look at my own answer. It can be improved but it solved my problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it using the `DBComponents` and `BoneCPComponents` traits in the `RepositoryModule`. With them, I could get a `Database` object and **inject it** to the repositories. This is the code I'm using for the module:

```
trait RepositoryModule extends BuiltInComponents with DBComponents with BoneCPComponents {
  lazy val database: Database = dbApi.database("default")
  lazy val userRepository = wire[UserRepository]
}
```

The database "default" will use the `db.default` configurations in the `application.conf`. The main problem with this solution is that you need to get the connections from the pool and return them when you're done. I don't know if it can be improved to mimic the `withConnection` method.

An example of the user repository using the injected database:

```
class UserRepository(db: Database) {
  def deleteAdults: Unit = {
    val connection: Connection = db.getConnection()
    val removed: Int = SQL("DELETE * FROM User WHERE age > 18").executeUpdate()(connection)
    connection.close()
  }
}
```

Comment: Found similar in MacWire's [play sample project](https://github.com/adamw/macwire/blob/master/examples/play24/app/com/softwaremill/play24/modules/DatabaseModule.scala). Play compile time DI docs are really sparse, would be nice to have a list of available DI components :\

Comment: re: closing connections, I suspect most play-ers are using Slick or other query dsl that handles resource management.